# Prove the limit of a sequence of functions converges to a point

Tags: real-analysis

Let$f_{n}$ be a convergent sequence of continuous real-valued function in $\mathbb{C}([0,1])$ with $f_{n} \rightarrow f$

If I have a sequence $x_{n}$ in $[0,1]$, with $x_{n} \rightarrow x$ and $y_{n} = f_{n}(x_{n})$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} y_{n} = f(x)$

The statement seems self evident but I don't really know where to start to prove it since all the theorems I know are for uniform continuity. Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Hint: Assuming uniform convergence of $f_n \to f$, then $f_n(x_n)$ is close to $f(x_n)$ and $f(x_n)$ is close to $f(x)$.

Comment: $|f_n(x_n)-f(x)|\leq|f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)|+|f(x_n)-f(x)|$ and note $f_n$  converges uniformly

Comment: @Mason I think I see what you're hinting at but doesn't that only work with uniformly continuous functions?

Comment: @ling We don't know that the functions are uniformly continuous so I don't think that we can use any of the epsilon continuity theorems?

Comment: @DicapriosWife2541 ......  continuous function on compact set is uniformly continuous

Comment: @ling Thanks! is there a way to derive uniform convergence from that? I'm just not really sure how to go about that!

Comment: @DicapriosWife2541 You are only asked to prove that $y_n \to f(x)$. This is just convergence of a sequence of real numbers.

Comment: Oh! I see, I just was just wondering because you said to note the uniform continuity which I was actually wondering about

Comment: The result is false without uniform convergence!

Answer (score 3):

The result is false without uniform convergence!

Consider $f_n(x)=x^n$, which converges pointwise to the characteristic function of $\{1\}$, and let $x_n=2^{-1/n}$.  Then
$$
x_n\to 1,
$$
but
$$
f_n(x_n)=1/2\to 1/2 \neq 1 =f(1).
$$

Comment: +1. However, if you just take $x_n=\left(\frac12\right)^\frac1n$ instead, you have an example in $[0, 1]$, which is the interval considered in the question.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, thanks.  This is what I had in mind but I ended up messing it up when writing.  It is now corrected based on your suggestion!